# Populating Test User with Check-in data

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-graph-api, checkin

How do you populate a Facebook Test User account with check-in data? I tried posting on the wall of the user with a Location entered in, but that did not seem to trigger a "check-in". Anyone run into this issue?

The only workaround I've found is to use a real user account.

Comment: I have not found any solution to this and have moved on from the project it applied to. No good solution was found unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in as the user, using the email and password provided when you created the user?

I've only worked with photos, but I've had luck with using the normal user interface for these kinds of tasks.

Also, you have to be careful to keep using the same user. The access token expires, so you have to renew it with the same user ID. I was accidentally creating new users.